# Remove unwanted fields from FormRequest

Tags: laravel

I am using `FormRequest` to validate incoming requests.

My `FormRequest`

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            "boxes" => ['required', 'array'],
            "boxes.*.box_id" => ['required', 'integer', 'exists:boxes,id'],
            "boxes.*.amount" => ['required', 'integer', 'gt:0'],
        ];
    }
```

If I send data to controller like:

```
{
    "boxes": [
        {
            "box_id": 1,
            "amount": 2,
            "unwanted": "unwanted"
        }
    ]
}
```

`Controller`

```
public function update(UpdateOrderRequest $request, Order $order)
    {
        $data = $request->validated();
        var_dump($data);
    }
```

Calling `$request->validated()` inside my controller returns everything inside `boxes`, but I want fields which are not present in my `FormRequest` to be removed.

So I only want to receive an array with `box_id` & `amount`

Isn't `FormRequest` expected to do so by default?

Comment: please share your controller code where you are calling $request->validated()

Comment: I added it to the question

Comment: No, FormRequest is not supposed to format the inputs, just validate what needs validation. So i suggest you do just that, format your inputs at the start of your controller instead of sending the bulk for update.

Answer (score 0):

On option would be that you pass the rules to the `$request->validate()` function.

```php
$validatedData = $request->validate([
  "boxes" => ['required', 'array'],
  "boxes.*.box_id" => ['required', 'integer', 'exists:boxes,id'],
  "boxes.*.amount" => ['required', 'integer', 'gt:0'],
]);

dd($validatedData); // will output only the field which validated
```

With Custome Request class you can use:
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#creating-form-requests

```php
// Retrieve a portion of the validated input data...
$validated = $request->safe()->only(['boxes.*.box_id', 'boxes.*.amount']);
$validated = $request->safe()->except(['boxes.*.box_id', 'boxes.*.amount']);
```